# Do-While getline equals '/n' with input validation

Tags: c++, validation, input, getline

I am working on a school project that is a cash register. I am having trouble with the input validation, I have a do while loop wherein the user needs to enter any char 1 to 6 or press enter to exit the loop, using getline(cin, choice), to input the char. I am having a problem validating the input while still allowing the '\n' to exit the loop, here is my code right now

```
    do {
    cout << "Please enter the number of the item then press enter, press enter to to confirm your order ";
    
    
    
    
    getline(cin, choice);

    while (choice.length() > 1 || choice[0] != '1' && choice[0] != '2' && choice[0] != '3' && choice[0] != '4' && choice[0] != '5' && choice[0] != '6' && choice[0] != '\n') {
        cout << "Invalid Input: please try again\n";
        
        getline(cin, choice);
    }
    
    
    


    switch (choice[0])
    {
    case '1': Hamburger++;
        break;

    case '2': Hotdog++;
        break;

    case '3': Frenchfries++;
        break;

    case '4': Potatochips++;
        break;

    case '5': Cookies++;
        break;

    case '6': Drink++;
        break;

    
    }
    
    }


 while (choice[0] != '\n');

    

Register(Hamburger, Hotdog, Frenchfries, Potatochips, Cookies, Drink);
}
```

I have tried multiple variations, but nothing is working, when i just press enter it says it is an invalid input. Any help would be helpful, thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not C. Please don't spam tag.

Comment: The **enter** (`'\n'`) is not stored in the `choice` string.

Comment: Change `while (choice[0] != '\n');` to `while (choice[0] != '\0');`

Comment: [`std::string::empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) probably isn't any safer these days, but I think it's a bit more readable than `choice[0] != '\0'`

Comment: my apologies, i figured this would apply to c as well.

Comment: @LiftedResearcher: C does not have `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::getline`. They only exist in C++.

Comment: Andreas Wenzel youre a life saver, that solved my problem. thank you soo much

Comment: And please format your code properly. This is very hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

As posted by Andreas Wenzel, the solution is to change

```
while (choice[0] != '\n');
```

to

```
while (choice[0] != '\0');
```

I hope this helps others. thank you all!

Comment: Reiterating above comment about [`std::string::empty`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty) being a more obvious test for an empty string. Plus it doesn't blow up if you somehow stumble across an old non-null-terminated `std::string` implementation (something I've never seen in the wild, but was legal).

Comment: @user4581301: Since C++11, it is required that `choice[0]` returns `'\0'` for an empty string. Therefore, in my opinion, it should be safe to use. On pre-C++11 implementations, when the string is empty, undefined behavior will already have been invoked by using `choice[0]` in the `switch` statement, so using it afterwards in the `while` condition will not matter. If you want to play it safe, `std::string::empty` will have to be checked before the `switch` statement.